# How to get one items from my Firebase realtime Database with Angular Ionic

Tags: angularjs, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

**this is my Realtime database
I want to find the article of the person connected and display infomation**

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCEga.png*]

This is my ionic script page

here are my imports
I can retrieve the id of the user to connect but
I cannot retrieve this information in
the real time database

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
    import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';

export class Tab3Page {

  public profileData: any;
  name: string;
prenom: string;



  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
     private db: AngularFireDatabase,
      private toast: ToastController,
      private navCtrl: NavController,
      private authService: FirebaseAuthServiceService) {
  

    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(
      (res)=>{
        this.profileData = res.uid;
        console.log(this.profileData);      
      }
    )

    this.db.list("users/"+this.profileData).valueChanges().subscribe(details => {
      this.name =details["name"];
      this.prenom = details["prenom"];
      console.log(details);
      
    })

}
    
}
```

Comment: "I cannot retrieve this information" Why not? What isn't working about the code that you shared? Are there any error messages displayed? What is the `console.log` output?

Comment: details must be the result that's getted from the realtime database for the current user. But it's not receved any data from realtime database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain, but I have a feeling you are attaching the database listener before the user is signed in. To fix that you need to move the subscribe call into the auth state listener"

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(
  (res)=>{
    this.profileData = res.uid;
    console.log(this.profileData);      
  }
  this.db.list("users/"+this.profileData).valueChanges().subscribe(details => {
    this.name =details["name"];
    this.prenom = details["prenom"];
    console.log(details);  
  })
)
```

If this indeed gets the data loaded you'll want to start managing the database subscription, as the `authState` may of course change over time.

Answer (score 0):

thank you Frank for your interventions
I saw my problem it was just a problem of local variables

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(
  (res)=>{
    this.profileData = res.uid;
    console.log(this.profileData);

    this.db.list("users/"+this.profileData).valueChanges().subscribe(details => {
      this.name = details[2];
      console.log(this.name);
      
    })
    
  }
)
```